# How to display two windows in two different display with tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, multiple-monitors, raspberry-pi4

After looking for solution for a week, I ask my question here hopping you can help me.

I work on a python project, using tkinter on a raspberry pi 4. As the raspberry allows me to use two different monitor, i would like to be able to display one window per screen.

My program is very basics. It created two differents windows (window = Tk() and root = tk.Toplevel(window)). I am trying to have window displays on screen 1 and root display on screen 2.

Do you think it is possible with tkinter or an other python library ?

thanks a lot for your kind help

---Edit----
The solution was found thanks to the comments given.

I actually used tk.geomtry to solve it. For those who are interessted :

> window.geometry(f'{width}x{height}+0+0') #first window on the first screen
> root.geometry(f'{width}x{height}+1920+0') #second window, with +1920 on x to put it on the second screen.

That works perfectly so thank you guys

Comment: You may take a look on [`screeninfo`](https://github.com/rr-/screeninfo) module.

Comment: Have you tried using the `geometry` method to adjust the geometry of each widget to be what you want?

Comment: like Bryan Oakley said did you try to play around with Tk().geometry("widthxheight+Left+Top") ?

Comment: Hello, I will try all those method for sure and let you know. Thanks for all your replies